# Laravel Eloquent Model doesn't commit touch() or save() on request

Tags: model, laravel, eloquent

This is the Route

```
Route::get('test', array('before' => 'auth', 'as' => 'asd', function()
{
$userid = '2';
$result = Messages::whereIn('from', array($userid, Auth::user()->id))
                    ->whereIn('to', array($userid, Auth::user()->id))
                    ->orderBy('sended', 'desc')
                    ->join('ucpm_users', 'ucpm_messages.from', '=', 'ucpm_users.id')->join('metadata_personas', 'ucpm_users.persona', '=', 'metadata_personas.id')
                    ->select('from','ucpm_users.username','metadata_personas.first_name','metadata_personas.last_name','message','ucpm_messages.created_at','ucpm_messages.updated_at','ucpm_messages.readed_at')
                    ->get();
    $result->each(function($message)
        {
                $message->touch();
        });
print_r($result);

}));
```

When its executed, its print the entry objects colection, like:

```
               [attributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [from] => 2
                        [username] => criser
                        [first_name] => Cristian
                        [last_name] => Leal
                        [message] => asdqweasd
                        [created_at] => 2013-06-07 20:11:31
                        [updated_at] => 2013-06-07 24:31:52
                        [readed_at] => 1986-09-08 00:00:00
                    )

                [original:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [from] => 2
                        [username] => criser
                        [first_name] => Cristian
                        [last_name] => Leal
                        [message] => asdqweasd
                        [created_at] => 2013-06-07 20:11:31
                        [updated_at] => 2013-06-07 24:31:52
                        [readed_at] => 1986-09-08 00:00:00
                    )
```

Without any error responce or anything. And both Attributes and Original arrays have changed the updated_at field with the current timestamp. Thats ok and is the way i want to work but.. they dont make any changes on the DB. There is no change on the updated_at field or anything. And its confusing to me understand why the model changes and show me that changes, but the changes are not comited.

Plus, if i change the "$message->touch()"; with a "$message->readed_at = '09-08-1986'; $message->save();" the result its the same: its feels like work, but no change are maded in the DB.

The route (not this route, this is just a test), recover all mensages from the current loggedin user with another user and print a json responce. My idea is, when its load, if the created_at date is the same as updated_at, the messages are unread, for that reason i want to change that (or use the readed_at field, whatever..).

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After couple of hours of hitting my head over brickwall I managed to find the root of this behaviour in source code of Model::save() method. You problem (same as was mine) is absence of explicitly defined unique (or primary) key as "public static $key" property of your Messages model. Default name of the key is 'id' and it is utilized for building updating query in Model::save(). No $key properly defined => no update happens. $key can be either primary key of the table, or any other non-primary but unique column. Then your model declaration may look like this:

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent
{
    public static $key = 'my_unique_key';
    ...
}
```

That solved my problem with touch() / timestamp() behaviour. Unfortunately, I didn't recall any references to this gotcha in API docs. It may seem just obvious for Laravel experts having clear understanding about forming UPDATE query in Model::save(), but for inexperienced Laravel user that would be a total brain-breaker.